# Orocrm dashboard displays a "You do not have permission to perform this action." error

Tags: nginx, ssl, orocrm

Ok, this is a fresh Orocrm install and i have the following errors:

[image]

When i dug a little in the network logs, this is what i found :

[image]

[image]

I don't know if its related, but these errors have started to show up when i enabled SSL support following all the instructions of the [WebSocket Connection Configuration](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/websockets/configuration/) page available in the orocrm doc.

This is the content of my **nginx config file**:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name crm.domain.tld;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name crm.domain.tld;
        root /home/whatever/crm/public;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/crm.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/crm.domain.tld/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        # ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        # ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES2;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/crm-php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

                include fastcgi_params;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

                internal;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                return 404;
        }

        location /ws {
                # redirect all traffic to localhost:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$is_args$args;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;

                # enables WS support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                # prevents 502 bad gateway error
                proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;

                reset_timedout_connection on;

                error_log /home/whatever/logs/oro_wss_error.log;
                access_log /home/whatever/logs/oro_wss_access.log;
        }

        error_log /home/whatever/logs/error.log;
        access_log /home/whatever/logs/access.log;
}
```

This is the content of my **parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: '%env(ORO_DB_HOST)%'
    database_port: '%env(ORO_DB_PORT)%'
    database_name: '%env(ORO_DB_NAME)%'
    database_user: '%env(ORO_DB_USER)%'
    database_password: '%env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD)%'
    database_server_version: '%env(ORO_DB_VERSION)%'
    database_driver_options: {  }

    mailer_transport: '%env(ORO_MAILER_DRIVER)%'
    mailer_host: '%env(ORO_MAILER_HOST)%'
    mailer_port: '%env(ORO_MAILER_PORT)%'
    mailer_encryption: '%env(ORO_MAILER_ENCRYPTION)%'
    mailer_user: '%env(ORO_MAILER_USER)%'
    mailer_password: '%env(ORO_MAILER_PASSWORD)%'

    websocket_bind_address: 0.0.0.0
    websocket_bind_port: 8080
    websocket_frontend_host: '*'
    websocket_frontend_port: 443
    websocket_frontend_path: 'ws'
    websocket_backend_host: '*'
    websocket_backend_port: 443
    websocket_backend_path: 'ws'
    websocket_backend_transport: 'ssl'
    websocket_backend_ssl_context_options: {  }

    web_backend_prefix: ''
    session_handler: session.handler.native_file
    secret: '%env(ORO_SECRET)%'
    installed: '*******************'
    assets_version: *******************
    assets_version_strategy: time_hash
    message_queue_transport: dbal
    message_queue_transport_config: null
    deployment_type: null
    liip_imagine.jpegoptim.binary: null
    liip_imagine.pngquant.binary: null

    env(ORO_DB_HOST): localhost
    env(ORO_DB_PORT): null
    env(ORO_DB_NAME): *******************
    env(ORO_DB_USER): *******************
    env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD): *******************
    env(ORO_DB_VERSION): null
    env(ORO_MAILER_DRIVER): smtp
    env(ORO_MAILER_HOST): 127.0.0.1
    env(ORO_MAILER_PORT): null
    env(ORO_MAILER_ENCRYPTION): null
    env(ORO_MAILER_USER): null
    env(ORO_MAILER_PASSWORD): null
    env(ORO_SECRET): *******************
```

This is the content of my **supervisor config file**:

```
***

[program:oro_web_socket]
command=php ./bin/console gos:websocket:server --env=prod
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
directory=/home/whatever/crm
user=whatever
redirect_stderr=true

[program:oro_message_consumer]
command=php ./bin/console oro:message-queue:consume --env=prod
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
directory=/home/whatever/crm
user=whatever
redirect_stderr=true
```

**var/logs/prod.log** doesn't input anything with `tail -f prod.log`.

**WSS Logs are empty**.

It might be related too, but after enabling the api sandbox in the Orocrm options **i was stuck in a loop** redirecting me every secs or so to the dashboard of Orocrm. I managed to somehow fix it by hitting the stop loading button of my browser at the right time. Once the option was disabled, no more loop redirection.

Any clues ? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its indeed tied to **SSL**, Moving from **unsafe** to **SSL** was a symptom of an underlying problem with deeper roots.

### For a bit of context this is what i did before i had the error messages:

When i started the installation of Orocrm i had no **SSL certificate**. I opened my browser and started configuring it up. When i was done configuring Orocrm i had to change the password since i was using a temporary password but before that i had to install the **SSL certificate**.

I've started to install the SSL certificate with **Letsencrypt tool**. Once i was done with it i've set up Orocrm to support SSL, then i re-opened orocrm again and things started to go wrong.

### What did provoke the error messages ?

Not clearing the cookies after moving from **unsafe** to **SSL**.

I'm not sure how are working things deep-down, but its probably because there was a an already avaiable `_csrf` cookie in my browser, it was not possible for the `https-_csrf` cookie to exist probably due to a condition somewhere.

### How to fix the error messages ?

Well you probably guessed it by now, its very simple. To fix the error messages you simply need to remove the `_csrf` cookie, and refresh the page. It will be replaced by a `https-_csrf` cookie instead.