# You do not have permission to perform this action after install orocrm

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

After fresh install orocommerce 5.0-beta.1 on custom domain with https got this error

[image]

I've try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704778/2119164) but it didn't work for me - the cookie is back with same name

UPD: If I try manually add `https-_csrf` cookie from browser console, everything works as expected. So question should be narrowed why js doesn't set cookie correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was because of nginx configuration.
I have need to set `fastcgi_param HTTPS` to `on`

[image]